# Counting the result of a count query - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to count the result of a count Query. My task is to count the number of Inspection that have violations (Where Passed = 0) and then count the results into 4 categories (Inspections with 1 violation, Inspections with 2 violations, Inspections with 3 or more violations). This is going to require a Union yes but I just want to get the 4 queries to run first. Here is what I have so far...

```
Select Count(I.ID),I.PermitID,I.Permit#
From InspectionItems I
Where I.PermitID in
   (Select SI.PermitID,Count(SI.ID) From InspectionItems SI
   Where SI.Passed <> 1
   And SI.Deleted <> 1
   Group By SI.PermitID
   Having Count(SI.ID) = 1)

Group By I.PermitID,I.Permit#
Order By I.PermitID,I.Permit#
```

- ID - Primary Key
- PermitID - Forigen Key
- Permit# - User Frienly Label

I get this error...

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the COUNT() from the select list of your subquery.  You only need it in the HAVING clause:

```
Select Count(I.ID),I.PermitID,I.Permit#
From InspectionItems I
Where I.PermitID in
   (Select SI.PermitID
 From InspectionItems SI
   Where SI.Passed <> 1
   And SI.Deleted <> 1
   Group By SI.PermitID
   Having Count(SI.ID) = 1)

Group By I.PermitID,I.Permit#
Order By I.PermitID,I.Permit#
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is returning both PermitID and the Count, which is why you're getting the error.  It needs to return a single column of values in order to be used as part of an "in," or a single value to be used for =, !=, etc.

It would probably be easiest to do the counts of violations first, and drop them into a temp table, then count from that table.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is using CTE:

```
;WITH SI AS (
   Select SI.PermitID
   From InspectionItems SI
   Where SI.Passed <> 1
      And SI.Deleted <> 1
   Group By SI.PermitID
   Having Count(SI.ID) = 1
)

Select Count(I.ID), I.PermitID, I.Permit#
From InspectionItems I
INNER JOIN SI
   ON I.PermitID = SI.PermitID
Group By I.PermitID,I.Permit#
Order By I.PermitID,I.Permit#
```

And you can do all queries in one, not using UNION

```
;WITH SI AS (
   Select SI.PermitID, Count(SI.ID) CountID
   From InspectionItems SI
   Where SI.Passed <> 1
      And SI.Deleted <> 1
   Group By SI.PermitID
)

Select Count(I.ID), I.PermitID, I.Permit#, SI.CountID
From InspectionItems I
INNER JOIN SI
   ON I.PermitID = SI.PermitID
Group By I.PermitID,I.Permit#
Order By I.PermitID,I.Permit#
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Tab Alleman advice I got the query to run but the problem was that I was also trying to count from the InspectionItems table and the numbers were not aggregating. So I used the main Inspections table and it seems to have forked...

```
Select Count(I.InspectionID)
From Inspections I
Where I.PermitID in
   (Select SI.PermitID
   From InspectionItems SI
   Where SI.Passed <> 1
   And SI.Deleted <> 1
   Group By SI.PermitID
   Having Count(SI.ID) = 1)
```

Thanks for the help.